# Liminf of a sequence obtained from Poisson Kernel

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits

Fix $\theta_0\in[0,2\pi),$ and let $\{z_n\}\subset\mathbb{D}$ be a sequence converging to $\exp(\iota\theta_0)\in\mathbb{T}.$ Find:

$$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-|z_n|^2}{1+|z_n|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(z_n\exp(-\iota\theta_0))},$$
where $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ denotes the real part of complex number $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator is better written as $|e^{i\theta_0}-z_n|^2$. The quotient $\frac{1-|z_n|^2}{|e^{i\theta_0}-z_n|^2}$ is obviously nonnegative. The value of its $\liminf$ will depend on what the sequence is. It can be anything from $0$ to $\infty$, including both extremes. To see why, write $z_n$ as $e^{i\theta_n}+r_ne^{it_n}$ where   $r_n\to 0$. How does 
$$\frac{1-|e^{i\theta_n}+r_ne^{it_n}|^2}{r_n^2} \tag1$$
  depend on $t_n$? Since any circle centered at $e^{i\theta_n}$ crosses the unit circle, we can choose $t_n$ to make $|e^{i\theta_n}+r_ne^{it_n}|$ as close to $1$ as we wish, regardless of what $r_n$ is. In particular, $\liminf$ can be $0$.

On the other hand, the choice $t_n=\theta_0+\pi$ makes
$$\frac{1-|e^{i\theta_n}+r_ne^{it_n}|^2}{r_n^2} = \frac{1-(1-r_n)^2}{r_n^2}=\frac{2-r_n}{r_n}\to\infty$$

And since (1) is a continuous function of $t_n$, any intermediate value can also be attained.

Comment: Yeah got you. In fact I was able to find the above stated conclusions, but thanks for your answer. In sequence $z_n$ it should be $\exp(\iota\theta_{0})$ rather than $\exp(\iota\theta_{n})$?